# How to read and write a file to maintain a numeric value

Tags: java, android, xml

I see a lot of examples how to write and read a file, but I wanted to maintain a integer type variable who will maintain score of a game either using XML or fileIO stream. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of SharedPreferences, which is a customized XML in Android to share settings/configuration among applications. 
Create a pair key/value write to 'pref' file, when you want to retrieve value, just call the approriate method, getInt(), getFloat(), getString()..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html 
Pretty much easy for beginners :)

Comment: well i had tried it just before few minuts bt its not working could u plzzz provide me a example....

Comment: Shared Prefs Example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref